# Is there a programmatic way to get man pages from Sphinx Builder as strings?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-click

I am working on a [Click CLI application](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/) and need the final `man` output from the [Sphinx manpage builder](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/_modules/sphinx/builders/manpage.html) to override Click's default `--help` output. I created an instance of sphinx like this:

```py
def create_sphinx_app():
    tempdir = tempfile.gettempdir()
    dir = "/path/to/docs/commands"
    sphinx = Sphinx(dir, dir, tempdir, tempdir, "man", freshenv=True)
    return sphinx
```

Docutils has a nice abstraction to obtain strings from a given docutils writer:

```py
app = create_sphinx_app()
man_page = publish_string(contents, writer=ManualPageWriter(ManualPageBuilder(app)))
```

This works when I'm not using sphinx extensions that need access to [Sphinx's Build environment](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/envapi.html#module-sphinx.environment).

However, I really need the extension so I tried using [Sphinx's version of a publisher](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/e867201cf28963e86f371d982b40de2ab8afd268/sphinx/io.py#L191-L220):

```py
app = self.create_sphinx_app()
pub = create_publisher(app, "rst", contents)
man_page = pub.publish()
```

I modified the publisher to use the [Sphinx ManPage writer](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/e867201cf28963e86f371d982b40de2ab8afd268/sphinx/writers/manpage.py) and the `docutils.io.StringInput` (also tried with `docutils.io.FileInput`) and `docutils.io.StringOutput`. Here's the stacktrace on running `cli --help`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/bin/cli", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('cli', 'console_scripts', 'cli')())
  File "/home/user/cli/cli/cli.py", line 428, in entrypoint
    cli()
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/user/cli/cli/cli.py", line 175, in invoke
    return super().invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1655, in invoke
    sub_ctx = cmd.make_context(cmd_name, args, parent=ctx)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 920, in make_context
    self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1378, in parse_args
    value, args = param.handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 2360, in handle_parse_result
    value = self.process_value(ctx, value)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 2322, in process_value
    value = self.callback(ctx, self, value)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1273, in show_help
    echo(ctx.get_help(), color=ctx.color)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 699, in get_help
    return self.command.get_help(self)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1298, in get_help
    self.format_help(ctx, formatter)
  File "/home/user/cli/cli/cli_util.py", line 28, in format_help
    help_render.render(ctx, file.read_text())
  File "/home/user/cli/cli/help.py", line 67, in render
    converted_content = self._convert_doc_content(ctx, contents)
  File "/home/user/cli/cli/help.py", line 100, in _convert_doc_content
    man_page = pub.publish()
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docutils/core.py", line 218, in publish
    self.settings)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/io.py", line 103, in read
    self.input = self.read_source(settings.env)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/io.py", line 113, in read_source
    env.events.emit('source-read', env.docname, arg)
  File "/home/user/cli/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/environment/__init__.py", line 463, in docname
    return self.temp_data['docname']
KeyError: 'docname'
```

I tried monkey patching Sphinx but I still can't get a `man` string out of it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: It must be possible, but probably not easy. I would guess you are the first person attempting something like this - though the use case is very interesting.

Comment: It's not clear how to reproduce the error. Can you provide a [mcve] that uses Sphinx only?